# Python OpenCV Fill in circle outlined by red

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

[image]

I have the image above and I just want to be able to get the shape outlined by the red and color everything in that shape to white. My code snippet below reads the image, uses the HSV value to try and get a mask of just the red pixel values, but for some reason it's not working. I don't end up getting a full circle and only just get a bunch of dots around the vicinity. Am I using the wrong HSV values?

```
im = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([0, 80, 80], np.uint8)
upper_red = np.array([20, 255, 255], np.uint8)
frame_threshold_red = cv2.inRange(hsv_im, lower_red, upper_red)
```

To get my HSV values, I'm doing this:

```
red = np.uint8([[[0, 0, 224]]])
hsv_red = cv2.cvtColor(red,  cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # 0, 255, 224
```

224 is the value of the red pixel. I checked that by looking at the actual matrix values.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this? Should I modify the HSV values or use an entirely different way? Thanks!

I'm currently getting something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you need a white *"floodfill"* starting from a point inside the red circle... https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your reply! But that would require me to manually select the point

Comment: If it's a circular shape, you can find the centroid of the red pixels, or the mean of left-most and right-most red pixels and mean of top-most and bottom-most red pixels as the seed for your floodfill. If it's potentially not circular we may need to think harder.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry for the delay, but thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started along the lines of my comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image and convert to HSV
im = cv2.imread("blob.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and upper limits of "red"
redlo = np.array([0, 80, 80], np.uint8)
redhi = np.array([20, 255, 255], np.uint8)

# Mask red pixels
R = cv2.inRange(HSV, redlo, redhi)

# Calculate x,y coordinate of centre of red pixels
M = cv2.moments(R) 
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]) 
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]) 

# Flood fill with white starting from centroid
_, res, _, _ = cv2.floodFill(im,mask=None,seedPoint=(cX,cY),newVal=(255,255,255))
```

[image]